# Any way to display referenced images stored in S3 in a Word doc WITHOUT code?

Tags: image, ms-word, reference

I currently have all my images on a Network drive that I reference from Word. I'm uploading the images to a bucket in S3 and wonder if I can do a referenced link from Word to the images on S3 ...simply...??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not end-user how-tos. In the future, please post questions like this at http://answers.microsoft.com or super User.

Choose **Insert>Quick Parts>Field**, select the **IncludePicture** field, enter the URL, check the option for **Data not stored with document**, then click on **OK**.

If you want to be able to resize the image, check both resize options in the Field dialog before OKing.